# How to crop a multipolygon relation without losing winding information?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am working on an overpass query to retrieve areas of water within fairly small bounding boxes (~1x1 km). The simplified query I started with is as follows:

```
[out:json][bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
  relation["natural"="water"];
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

[overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1A8A)

While this works and gives me all the data I need, for large bodies of water this gives me much more data than I want (i.e., all nodes for the entire body of water).

I can discard all output outside the region of interest:

```
[out:json][bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
  relation["natural"="water"];
);
out geom({{bbox}});
```

[overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1A8z)

but this no longer allows me to tell which side of the resulting way (segment) is actually water (i.e., "inside" the multipolygon), since the winding direction of water ways/multipolygons is not specified (like it is for coastlines).

How can I go about retrieving sufficient information to tell me which side of the cropped multipolygon is "inside"? For example, it would be sufficient to include all nodes within the bounding box, as well as the first and last node of each way.